# Mean of Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ have a Poisson distribution with double mode at $x=1$ and $x=2$. Find $ P(X=0)$.Here is my solution: $$\mu= \frac {p(2) 2!}{p(1)}$$ Then how can find the mean? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: For what value of $\lambda$ does $e^\lambda P\{X=1\} = \frac{\lambda}{1!}$ equal $e^\lambda P\{X=2\} = \frac{\lambda^2}{2!}$?

Answer (score 2):

The mode is the most likely value to occur. Poisson takes only discrete values, so you are given that $$P(X=1)=P(X=2)$$ which implies that $$e^{-λ}\frac{λ^1}{1!}=e^{-λ}\frac{λ^2}{2!} \iff λ=\frac{λ^2}{2} \iff λ^2-2λ=0 \iff λ(λ-2)=0$$ so $λ=0$ which is rejected (since $λ>0$) or $λ=2$ which is acceptable. Thus $X \sim$ Poisson$(λ=2)$ and therefore $$P(X=0)=e^{-2}\frac{2^0}{0!}=e^{-2}\cdot 1= 0.135335$$